# How to retrieve data as a string, not a dictionary, from firebase database and add that to an array?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase database set up like so...

> post-items--|

```
         What's your favorite color?--|
        -- addedByUser: "Michael Ruddy"

            --question: "What's your favorite color?"
```

I want to retrieve the question "What's your favorite color?" from the live database and put that value as a String into an array.  Also I need each new question added to automatically join the array.

My current code only recieves a dictionary value which, when converted, is in a random order.

```
func startObservingDB() {
    dbRef.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot:DataSnapshot) in
        let postDict = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] ?? [:]
        let newPosts = postDict

        self.tableView.reloadData()
        print (self.posts)
    }) { (error) in
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really structure your data like this

```
post_items
   -Yuh8...
       question: "What's your favorite color"
       asked_by: "Michael Ruddy"
```

and the code to read in all questions, one at a time, and then look for newly added questions would be

```
let postsRef = self.ref.child("post_items")
postsRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
    let dict = snapshot.value as! [String: Any]
    let q = dict["question"] as! String
    let a = dict["asked_by"] as! String
    print("\(a) asked \(q)")
    //add data to the array
    //tableView.reloadData
})
```

The key parent node of each post (Yuh8...) is created with childByAutoId.

Comment: @MichaelR. Excellent! If it worked and it helped but sure to accept it so it can help others as well!